# "The value passed for ConditionOperator.In is empty" with ConditionExpression using ConditionOperator.In against an empty array operand

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have some code as follows:

```
    QueryExpression qxEmpty = new QueryExpression("systemuser");
    object[] guids = (new Guid[] { }).Cast<object>().ToArray();
    ConditionExpression c = new ConditionExpression("systemuserid", ConditionOperator.In, guids);
    qxEmpty.Criteria.AddCondition(c);
    EntityCollection ecEmpty = service.RetrieveMultiple(qxEmpty);
```

It fails on the last line with a FaultException:

> The value passed for ConditionOperator.In is empty

If I initialize the `guids` variable to contain one or more valid guids existing in the target CRM, I get the expected result.

So why does RetrieveMultiple throw an exception when I have a condition that asks whether a value is a member of the empty set? The condition should evaluate to false and RetrieveMultiple should return an empty EntityCollection, not throw an exception, shouldn't it?

MSDN seems to suggest it's some problem with the method overloading on ConditionExpression constructor, and to make sure that the appropriate object type is used, but as far as I can tell I'm doing it properly, passing an array of objects:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334419(v=crm.7).aspx

I'm using version 7.1.0.1085 of the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk

Edit:  I guess I'm not asking the right question. How do I pass an empty set to ConditionExpression for use with ConditionOperator.In?

Edit 2:
Okay, here's the SQL I'm trying to translate to QueryExpression.

```
SELECT *
FROM SystemUser
WHERE SystemUserId IN
(
   SELECT SystemUserid
   FROM SystemUser
   WHERE X=Y
)
```

I've translated this roughly as follows:

```
QueryExpression qxEmpty = new QueryExpression("systemuser");
object[] guids = getGuids(); // calls a method that executes the subquery
ConditionExpression c = new ConditionExpression("systemuserid", ConditionOperator.In, guids);
qxEmpty.Criteria.AddCondition(c);
EntityCollection ecEmpty = service.RetrieveMultiple(qxEmpty);
```

The problem with the above is it fails when the subquery has no values. In SQL, it doesn't fail, it gives me an empty set, which is what I want as a result of the QueryExpression.

Edit 3:
Oops, I suddenly realized why this is a stupid question. Since CRM doesn't support subqueries, and I have to do this in two separate queries anyway, I might as well not do the second query when the list is empty, because I already know the result and so shouldn't spend the resources.  So although it might seem more elegant to support passing an empty array, in fact the exception is a nice signal for me to add the explicit checks in the code.

Comment: Did you try making guids a Guid[], not object[] ?  There is an object[] overload which I think the compiler is using. See this https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmdavidjennaway/archive/2011/05/25/unexpected-error-with-conditionoperator-in-and-typed-arrays

Comment: @Mangist Yes, I've tried that.  If I replace the second line of my above code with Guid[] guids = new Guid[] { }; I get the same exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to Matt's answer, if you look at the SDK source code, the collection of values is never initialized,not even with an empty `DataCollection` object when empty arguments are passed. So this is an intended behavior, where in, using an `IN` condition expects at least one parameter.

SDK source code:

```
public ConditionExpression(string entityName, string attributeName, ConditionOperator conditionOperator, params object[] values)
{
  this._entityName = entityName;
  this._attributeName = attributeName;
  this._conditionOperator = conditionOperator;
  if (values == null)
      return;
  this._values = new DataCollection<object>((IList<object>) values);
}
```

Update #1: based on comment `SELECT * FROM systemuser where systemuserid IN ( select systemuserid from systemuser where 1=2)`

Query expressions have limitations, not every SQL query can be translated directly. From a SQL perspective, using `IN` definitely has some performance advantages over using multiple `WHERE` conditions, but in this particular case, there is no option but to use `Where` - `OR` in conjunction.

Update #2: After all the comments:

```
object[] guids = getGuids(); // calls a method that executes the subquery
if (guids == null || !guids.Any()) return new EntityCollection(new List<Entity>());
ConditionExpression c = new ConditionExpression("systemuserid", ConditionOperator.In, guids); 
//rest of the query
```

Comment: But I am giving it one parameter:  an empty array - I'm not passing null.  I'm not understanding what I should be passing instead.

Comment: Do you mean WHERE - OR?   Like instead of using ConditionOperator.In in a single COnditionExpression against an array, I use ConditionOperator.Equals against each value in the array (with multiple condition expressions), and then add all those COnditionExpressions to an OR filter?

Comment: Yes, multiple conditional operators and group them by `OR`, updated my answer too. 1 conditional operator per array item.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems cumbersome, but at least it makes sense. I'll probably accept this answer unless someone else suggests a way I can pass an empty set for use with ConditionOperator.In.

Comment: What is the purpose of passing an empty array parameter into the condition. It is almost as equivalent to saying `Where` `SystemUserId` is `NULL` (something that is non-existent), because your query is along similar lines `where systemuserid in 'nothing' (empty array of guids)`

Comment: I'm not *always* passing an empty array.  The condition I want is WHERE X is IN a set of values, but I don't know how many values there are.  Could be zero, could be many. But my ConditionExpression fails when there are zero values in the set. So, in my example, I'm looking for the equivalent of SELECT * FROM systemuser where systemuserid IN (NULL)

Comment: Use `ConditionOperator.Null`, which is the equivalent of saying `SystemUserId` is/in `Null`. `new ConditionExpression("systemuserid", ConditionOperator.Null);`

Comment: So I guess you're saying I CANNOT pass an empty set to ConditionOperator.In, and I have to explicitly check whether my subquery is empty.  Arrgh that sucks.

Comment: Thanks for your work.  Your suggested workarounds in Update#1 and Update#2 would work, but I don't like what they would do to my code.  I've added another answer which I think is a more elegant workaround.

Comment: To reply to your question "What is the purpose of passing an empty array parameter into the condition", it's because a result set can be empty- that's valid use case.  It's not like saying "Where SystemUserId Is NULL" - that's a completely different query.  It's equivalent to asking the question "Is the value X in the set of values Y?"  Which is a perfectly legitimate question that can always be answered, yes or no, for *any* Y, even one that happens to contain NO values.

Comment: I agree that the question "Is the value X in nothing" is undefined, because we don't know the type of nothing, so we don't even know what "in" means due to lack of context.

Comment: Oh wait, I guess I get it now.  CRM doesn't support subqueries, so since I have to do a separate query anyway, I should explicitly check the array to make sure it's not empty before spending the resources to go to CRM.  Geez, what didn't I understand about that before?

Comment: does any() get executed twice here?

Answer (score 4):

To me the exception is correct as the query is invalid. The error is explicitly telling you the "In" operator cannot have an empty value. The equivalent in SQL would be

```
SELECT * FROM systemuser where systemuserid IN ()
```

Which would also be a syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

**EDIT** Based on all the comments it sounds like you're taking in dynamic input (which could be <s>null</s> empty) and want to be able to run your query with an "In" operator. Best way would probably be check collection and don't execute the query if it's empty. If you still need to execute the query you could do something like:

```
var input = new Guid[] {};
var values = input.Length == 0 ?
                "<value></value>" :
                String.Join("", input.Select(x => $"<value>{x}</value>"));

_orgService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(
    $@"<fetch>
        <entity name='systemuser'>
            <attribute name='fullname'/>
            <filter>
                <condition attribute='systemuserid' operator='in'>
                    {values}
                </condition>
            </filter>
        </entity>
    </fetch>"));
```

Comment: Well, yeah, that's a syntax error, but to me the equivalent query would be something like SELECT * FROM systemuser where systemuserid IN ( select systemuserid from systemuser where 1=2).  How do I express that in the QueryExpression?  I know I can probably do hacky things like check whether the array is empty, and if so, not pass it, or not execute the expression, but I was hoping for the correct way of doing it.

Comment: What you are describing is not "hacky" - it is the correct way of doing it. What you describe in your SQL query is not the equivalent of what you are asking here. You are not providing a sub-query that returns no records you are explicitly providing no input to the `IN` operator.

Comment: So maybe I wasn't asking the right question.  How do I pass an empty set to ConditionExpression for use with ConditionOperator.In?

Comment: @pabrams maybe if you wrote the query you're trying to write in SQL we could help with the best way to convert it to Fetch or a QueryExpression. SQL sub queries aren't supported by Fetch or QueryExpressions, but joins (including left-outer) as well as nested ORs and ANDs are. Here is a link on a "Not In" query: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531006.aspx

Comment: @Nicknow Any hints on how to properly "provide a sub-query that returns no records" to the ConditionExpression?  I'm not aware of any way to pass a sub-query - as far as I can tell, it's expecting a value or a set of values, i.e. the result of a sub-query, not the sub-query itself.

Comment: You don't. This isn't SQL. If you want to use FetchXML you can use @MattDearing's example - which works perfectly. `QueryExpression` and `FetchExpression` (i.e., FetchXml) are not 1:1 matches, and neither is a 1:1 to SQL.

Comment: @MattDearing Thanks for your work, but I disagree with you about the 'equivalent sql statement', because as you pointed out, there's a syntax error, but there's no compiler nor syntax error in my QueryExpression. I'm also confused about your mention of "sounds like you're taking in some kind dynamic input (which could be null)", like that's some kind of a mysterious thing and I shouldn't be surprised that an exception gets thrown.  To me, it's obvious that if someone asks whether a specific value is "in" an empty set, the answer should always be FALSE.  Not ERROR.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134639/discussion-between-nicknow-and-pabrams).